# Displaying millisecnds in wp8

Tags: c#, php, xaml, windows-phone

I want to display the milliseconds in a message box using c# in my WP8 app.milliseconds must be from 1st january till the time the message box is displayed.just as the time() in php.
i have used datetime.now.milliseconds but this returns the milliseconds from the start of the day.how to do this?

Comment: Use timespan, subtract now from the day you want.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Operations on dates are possible using the DateTime class.

It is possible to substract two different DateTime instance, which will give a TimeSpan object exposing all the time informations you need: days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.

Example:

```
DateTime dtJanurary = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.Now - dtJanurary);

double ms = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
```